# How to print formatted date in F#

Tags: .net, f#

I have this date in F#

```
let myDate = new DateTime(2015, 06, 02)
```

And want to output it like "2015/06/02" in the console window. I tried:

```
Console.WriteLine(sprintf "%s" myDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
```

But this does not compile (compiler says, "*Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized*")

How would I output the date as "2015/06/02"?

UPDATE:

As commented by Panagiotis Kanavos, this will work:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", myDate)
```

Comment: *Why* did you put `sprintf` inside `WriteLine`? Why did you use it at all, since you already called `ToString`? WriteLine accepts a format string so you can simply write `Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}",myDate)`. All the methods you used, `sprintf`, `ToString`, `WriteLine`, can format strings. There is no need to mix them, just use one of them

Comment: Thankyou, the solution you provided works.

Comment: To fix the compiler error, put the ToString call in parentheses: `Console.WriteLine(sprintf "%s" (myDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")))`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You easily can call the `ToString` overload that takes a format string:

```
let formatted = myDate.ToString "yyyy/MM/dd"
```

However, `sprintf` doesn't support that in short form, but you could do this:

```
printfn "%s" (myDate.ToString "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

You can also [define a function for this purpose](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/05/08/stringf), if you feel that calling a method on an object isn't sufficiently functional:

```
let inline stringf format (x : ^a) = 
    (^a : (member ToString : string -> string) (x, format))
```

which would enable you to compose functions in many interesting ways. You could for example write to the console like this:

```
myDate |> stringf "yyyy/MM/dd" |> printfn "%s"
```

or like this:

```
(stringf "yyyy/MM/dd" >> printfn "%s") myDate
```

Comment: If your current culture isn't using the '/' as separator I think you need to escape it to get what you want.
like this: myDate.ToString "yyyy\/MM\/dd".
In my culture the output of myDate.ToString "yyyy/MM/dd" is something like ""2015.06.02"