# How to use sprintf to format an integer with commas as thousands separators

Tags: f#, inline

How does one use sprintf to format an integer to display commas as thousands separators?

I know how to do it using String.Format, but I can't find a way to do it using sprintf.

EDIT: Based on  Fyodor Soikin's comment below, I tried this code:

```
printf "%a" (fun writer (value:int) -> writer.Write("{0:#,#}", value)) 10042
let s = sprintf "%a" (fun writer (value:int) -> writer.Write("{0:#,#}", value)) 10042
```

The printf call works (but writes to standard output, whereas I want to get a string I can assign to the Text or Content property of a WPF control, for instance).

The sprintf call fails with error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Write' is not defined.

If I could fix this error, then this might be the most direct solution possible, and when combined with partial application would be as concise as a built-in version.

Comment: Of interest: [How to print formatted date in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590473/how-to-print-formatted-date-in-f/30593441#30593441)

Comment: On use of sprintf : https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/

Answer (score 6):

Since you can't do that with the Printf module, I do it like this:

```
/// Calls ToString on the given object, passing in a format-string value.
let inline stringf format (x : ^a) = 
    (^a : (member ToString : string -> string) (x, format))
```

And then call it like this:

```
someNumber |> stringf "N0"
```

Comment: That's interesting, but I guess I can't award the "X Prize", since using ToString is no better than using String.Format. I was able to use your solution in the example below, along with calling ToString directly in an OO fashion. But I'm still an F# beginner, so I'm very confused by your ^a syntax. I'm familiar with 'a (a generic value), but what is ^a? Thanks!

    let x = 42345 |> stringf "N0" // --> val x : string = "42,345"
    let x' = 44325L.ToString("N0") // --> val x' : string = "44,325"

Comment: The `inline` function with the `^a` can be thought of as basically duck-typing. In this case, the `stringf` function will work with any object that has a `ToString` method that takes a string as input and returns a string. If you try to use it with an object that doesn't have that overload for ToString, you'll get a compiler error. In other words, `stringf` is a functional way of calling `ToString(string)` just like the built-in `string` function is a functional way of calling `ToString()`. As far as "no better than using String.Format" what makes you think there IS a better?

Comment: Technically it's a `Member Constraint Invocation Expression`. It is described in the [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/).

Comment: @JoelMueller re "what makes you think there IS a better": as with all scientific experiments, you never know until you try. It's becoming obvious that there is no built-in way for sprintf to do this, but perhaps there is a way to overload it with an extension method. I Do appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Of interest: [How to print formatted date in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590473/how-to-print-formatted-date-in-f/30593441#30593441)

Answer (score 2):

This works but there should be a simpler way.

```
let thousands(x:int64) = 
    System.String.Format("{0:#,0}", x)

let s = sprintf "%s" (thousands(0L))
printfn "%s" s

let s = sprintf "%s" (thousands(1L))
printfn "%s" s

let s = sprintf "%s" (thousands(1000L))
printfn "%s" s

let s = sprintf "%s" (thousands(1000000L))
printfn "%s" s

0
1
1,000
1,000,000
```

A slightly better version

```
let printNumber (x : int) : string =
    System.String.Format("{0:N0}",x)
```

Comment: Sorry, that's cheating. I'm looking for an answer that doesn't rely on String.Format. In other words, using only sprintf, not .NET framework libraries. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: First, there is no way to do this with F# format specifiers. Second, sorry to disappoint, but the F# format functions do use .NET FW libraries underneath, specifically `TextWriter`. And you can actually hook right into that underlying `TextWriter` by using format specifier `%t` or `%a`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function:

```
let thousands n =
    let v = (if n < 0 then -n else n).ToString()
    let r = v.Length % 3 
    let s = if r = 0 then 3 else r
    [   yield v.[0.. s - 1]
        for i in 0..(v.Length - s)/ 3 - 1 do
            yield v.[i * 3 + s .. i * 3 + s + 2]
    ]
    |> String.concat ","
    |> fun s -> if n < 0 then "-" + s else s
```

and here is another one with some helper extension members:

```
type System.String with
    member this.Substring2(from, n) = 
        if   n    <= 0           then ""
        elif from >= this.Length then ""
        elif from <  0           then this.Substring2(0, n + from)
        else this.Substring(from, min n (this.Length - from))
    member this.Left             n  = if n < 0 
                                    then this.Substring2(0, this.Length + n)
                                    else this.Substring2(0, n              )
    member this.Right            n  = this.Substring2(max 0 (this.Length - n), this.Length)

let thousands (n:int) =
    let rec thousands acc = 
        function
        | "" -> acc
        | x  -> thousands (x.Right 3 + if acc = "" then "" else "," + acc) (x.Left -3)
    if n < 0 then -n else n
    |> string
    |> thousands ""
    |> fun s -> if n < 0 then "-" + s else s
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure C...

```
char* StringFormatIntCommas(char* szDest, int64_t s64Value)
{
    char        szTemp[32];
    uint64_t    u64Value = ABS(s64Value);                           // Drop Signage

    if (szDest == NULL)                                             // Validate params
        return NULL;

    while (u64Value)
    {
        strcpy(szTemp, szDest);                                     // Preserve Back end
        if (u64Value >= 1000)
            sprintf(szDest, ",%03d", (int32_t)(u64Value % 1000));   // Next triple ',00n'
        else
            sprintf(szDest, "%d", (int32_t)(u64Value % 1000));      // Last triple 'n'
        u64Value = u64Value / 1000;                                 // Reduce
        strcat(szDest, szTemp);                                     // Append Back end
    }

    if (s64Value < 0)                                               // Pre-Append Negative Sign
    {
        strcpy(szTemp, szDest);                                     // Preserve Back end
        strcpy(szDest, "-");                                        // Negative sign up front
        strcat(szDest, szTemp);                                     // Append back end
    }

    return szDest;
}
```